# ORA-00942: table or view does not exist ( on another schema on same DB )

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, database-administration

USER_OBJECTS is accessible when accessed by the schema/user **HR** i.e

```
select count(*) from USER_OBJECTS; returns 1005
```

However when we execute the following query using **DEV** schema/user it gives the **ORA-00942** error.

```
select count(*) from HR.USER_OBJECTS
```

**ORA-00942: table or view does not exist**

I connected with **HR** user and have given the select grants on the USER_OBJECTS to **DEV** schema. using the following query

```
grant select on USER_OBJECTS To DEV
```

However, executing select on table Person of HR is fine using the **DEV** schema/username.

select count(*) from HR.PERSON

Please, advise what should I do to get this done? What does it man that USER_OBJECTS is owned by the current user ?

Comment: user_objects is a system view limited to the currently logged in user.  you need to use `SELECT count(*) from All_Objects where owner = 'HR'`

Comment: @xQbert you should post that as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User_objects is a system view limited to the currently logged in user.

you need to use

```
SELECT count(*) from All_Objects where owner = 'HR'
```

Answer (score 1):

The view, USER_OBJECTS, is owned by the user, SYS, and there is a public synonym, USER_OBJECTS, which points to SYS.USER_OBJECTS... so USER_OBJECTS is available from any user without schema prefix, SYS.USER_OBJECTS.

The view, USER_OBJECTS, always shows the objects of the current user. This means the result of `select count(*) from USER_OBJECTS` may be for HR, 1005, and for SCOTT, 20.

You do not need to grant any privileges to query the view. Any user who can connect to the database can query this view.